# Confusion with the principles of Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I was learning Redux and came across the three principles of it:

- single source of truth,
- state is read-only,
- changes are made with pure functions.

I understood the idea behind the first principle but still find myself in confusion with the other two.

Concerning `state is read-only`, I got that we can update state only via `actions` and is it true that the reason for using `actions` to update state is **predictability** which ensures that there is no **unexpected** and **sudden** changes and thanks to actions it is clear when and how state is changed(action is kinda like protection of state being changed unexpectedly)? Right?

Lastly, about `changes are made with pure functions` yeah I understood that it also gives predictability but cannot get the actual and clear reason behind that. \

Thus I really need your kind help